# ListView doesn't show the correct result from a query if I return an ArrayList<CustomClass> from DB and use a SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter, simpleadapter

Sorry If I'm being a fool here, but I'm trying to use the **LIKE** operator to find all the records in a table CLIENTE (CUSTOMER) which name contains a string.

This is the code I use:

```
   public Cursor searchClienteByRazonSocial(String razon) {
        String where = CLIENTE_RAZONSOCIAL + " LIKE ? AND " + CLIENTE_ATENDIDO + " =?"; 
        String[] whereArgs = { "%" + razon + "%" , "0" };           

        this.openReadableDB();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(CLIENTE_TABLE, null, where, whereArgs, null,
                null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        this.closeDB();
        return cursor;

    }
```

The pattern works, but the problem comes when I specify names with a white space in the middle such as :

```
"Juan Carlos"
"Maria de Fatima"
```

`"Juan "` and `"Maria "` will match and be returned, but `"Juan C"`  and `"Maria d"` won't return anything.

I've already tried  with single quotation marks `"'%" + name.trim() + "%'"`, but it didn't work either.

In this [link](http://goo.gl/CxTOVL) you can find a copy of my database (QuickOrder.db)
In that database the table I want to query is called : **Cliente** and the column **razon_social**

This is an example of the query I trying to make from Android :

```
 SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE razon_social LIKE '%jose l%'
```

Am I missing something here?

## **********EDIT************

This is very strange , I think I kinda solve this, but I don't understand why this was happening.
This is what was trying to do

```
public class BuscarClientesActivity extends Activity implements
        OnQueryTextListener, OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView mResultsListView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;

    private QuickOrderDB mDB;
    private ClientesListAdapter mClientesAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Cliente> mClientes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar_clientes);

        //
        mClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        mResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resultadosClientesListView);
        mClientesAdapter = new ClientesListAdapter(BuscarClientesActivity.this,
                mClientes);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.buscarClientesSearchView);
        mSearchView.setIconified(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        mResultsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // get database
        mDB = new QuickOrderDB(getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (!newText.isEmpty()) {
            displayResults(newText);
        } else {
            mResultsListView.setAdapter(mClientesAdapter);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        displayResults(query);
        return false;
    }

    private void displayResults(String query) {
        new FiltrarClientes().execute(query);
    }
}
```

Since I didn't want to query the DB inside the UI thread I moved all the code I use to pull the data from the DB to an AsyncTask as follows. **This AsyncTask is coded as a inner class in the *BuscarClientesActivity* class shown above**

```
class FiltrarClientes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(String... params) {
            // get the query
            String query = params[0];
            Cursor resultados = BuscarClientesActivity.this.mDB
                    .searchClienteByRazonSocial(query);
            return resultados;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            // create a List of Map<String,?> objects
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            while (result.moveToNext()) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("codigo","["+ String.valueOf(result.getInt(QuickOrderDB.CLIENTE_ID_COL))+ "]");
                map.put("razonSocial",result.getString(QuickOrderDB.CLIENTE_RAZONSOCIAL_COL));
                map.put("direccion",result.getString(QuickOrderDB.CLIENTE_DIRECCION_COL));
                data.add(map);
            }

            // close the cursor
            if (result != null) {
                result.close();
            }
            // create the resource, from, and to variables
            int resource = R.layout.resultados_clientes_item;
            String[] from = { "codigo", "razonSocial", "direccion" };
            int[] to = { R.id.itemCodClienteTextView,
                    R.id.itemRazonSocTextView, R.id.itemDireccionTextView };

            // create and set the adapter
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    BuscarClientesActivity.this, data, resource, from, to);
            mResultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
```

As you can see, I was using a **SimpleAdapter** to display the data in the ListView. This was the code that was giving such a bad time. Then, after some trial and error, I realized that it wasn't a SQLite problem, but a problem with the type of adapter I was using, and this is the part I don't understand, because when I changed my code and instead of a SimpleAdapter I used a SimpleCursorAdapter everything work almost as expected.

```
private void displayResults(String query) {
        // new FiltrarClientes().execute(query);
        Cursor resultados = mDB
                .searchClienteByRazonSocial(query);

        if (resultados != null) {

            String[] from = new String[] { QuickOrderDB.CLIENTE_ID,
                    QuickOrderDB.CLIENTE_RAZONSOCIAL,
                    QuickOrderDB.CLIENTE_DIRECCION };

            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.busqCodClienteTextView,
                    R.id.busqRazonSocTextView, R.id.busqDireccionTextView };

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.resultados_clientes_item, resultados, from, to);
            mResultsListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        }       
}
```

As is shown above, I'm not using a AsyncTask, instead I'm running this query on the UI thread and also now I'm using a **SimpleCursorAdapter**.

Now this brings me to two questions:

- First, what is the reason my code didn't work when I used a **SimpleAdapter**?
- Second, do you know of any efficient way of querying a database without using a **Content Provider**. Would it be enough to use an AsyncTask??

Thanks again.

Comment: Are the spaces really spaces in your data, and there's equal amount of space there?

Comment: Worksforme, that's why it would be interesting to see your actual data.

Comment: Works for me, I get IDs 1251 and 2757.

Comment: `An easy adapter to map STATIC data to views defined in an XML file` according to doc

Comment: use libraries if you do not like really working with db in a low level for example ormlite or greendao.

Comment: @mmlooloo but please tell, wouldn't it have been the same to use a SimpleAdapter or a SimpleCursorAdapter?? I can't understand why it worked with one type of Adapter and not with the other. Now as for my second question, is it OK to use AsyncTask to query my DB? I seen there are other alternatives, but they all work with ContentProviders :'(

Comment: @mmlooloo So a SimpleAdapter won't work when reading data from a Table?

Comment: `ContentProviders` and your local database is two different things that are very similar, you do not need to use `ContentProviders` if for example your app dos not provide data for other apps. `is it OK to use AsyncTask to query my DB?` yes !!`So a SimpleAdapter won't work when reading data from a Table` i do not know exactly but i see some posts that have issues about that and when they switch to other adapter it works, i have not tried myself to see exactly what it is.

Comment: @mmlooloo that's exactly why I don't have a ContentProvider. Sorry for keep asking the same thing, but would it still be OK to use an AsyncTask for this purpose, knowing that I'll be executing this AsyncTask over and over again as the user types in a new letter in the SearchView widget ?

Comment: Yes it is a recommended way to use database and you are on a right way, always do heavy work in other thread also people do not do it.

Comment: i also recommend you if you are going to implement search to see the docs about it.

Comment: @mmlooloo Any specific point I must pay close attention to?

Comment: i think you want to implement search suggestion or search history and the docs provide that example using `contentprovider` but the back end data of that is up to you so you can provide that back end by DB. if also you want to use content provider see creating provider in docs. i just want to make sure you do not miss anything.

Comment: Thank you @mmlooloo I really appreciate all your comments and suggestions, you're one of the few people that is always willing to help (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] whereArgs={"'%" + name.trim() + "%' OR " + "'% " + name.trim() + " %' OR " + "'% " + name.trim() + "%' OR " + "'%" + name.trim() + " %'"};
```

This return all names with the filter.

Comment: Are you sure? At first glance there's a syntax error.

Comment: The correct: String[] whereArgs={"'%" + name.trim() + "%' OR " + "'% " + name.trim() + " %' OR " + "'% " + name.trim() + "%' OR " + "'%" + name.trim() + " %'"};

Comment: Have you test it yourself? Didn't work over here. Strangely I'm trying the same and much to my surprise what works in SQLiteBrowser doesn't work when tested in Android

Comment: @Axel That's exactly what's happening to me. I'm starting to wonder is this doesn't have anything to do with the AsyncTask I use to query the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the quote marks around the placeholder in the `WHERE` clause template:

```
String where = CLIENTE_RAZONSOCIAL + " LIKE '?' AND " + CLIENTE_ATENDIDO + " =?";
String[] whereArgs = { "%" + razon + "%" , "0" };
```

If you put the quote marks in the `whereArgs` string, then they will be escaped when interpolated by the call to `db.query()`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I think I should change the title of the question because as I mentioned in **Edit** part of it, this turned out to be something that has nothing to do with the LIKE operator but with the type of **adapter** I was using (A SimpleAdapter)

Comment: Sorry to bother you @TedHopp , but I really need to understand what's happening here. Do you have any idea of what might be the cause of the problem I described about the used of a SimpleAdapter with results from a DB. Is there anything in the doc against the use of a SimpleAdapter when pulling data from a DB?

Comment: I don't know why your `AsyncTask` method didn't work. But instead of using an `AsyncTask` or a `ContentProvider`, try using an `AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>`. You can write it to query your db directly in the background so you don't need a `ContentProvider`. You get all the benefits of using a `Loader` and don't need to worry about things like how to deal with your activity being destroyed and re-created on a configuration change (since the framework takes care of that).

Comment: do you have any examples?? I can't find any example that don't use a ContentProvider or that is related specifically to a db

Comment: @eddy - I used [LoaderEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) as inspiration for writing my own `AsyncTaskLoader`. Once you get the idea (which I did by studying the LoaderEx source as well as the example in the `AsyncTaskLoader` docs), it's pretty easy to do. I didn't use LoaderEx because it does way too much for what I needed (plus the warnings about it being a discontinued project were a little off-putting).

Comment: @eddy - I also found [this tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) extremely helpful (mainly because I was a total novice regarding loaders when I started).

Comment: Thank you @TedHopp I'll definitely check that tutorial. Once again, thank you very much for always taking the time to help me.